# How to store multiple plots to be viewed later

Tags: plotting

I need to be able to import my data and create multiple listlineplots, but my inputs for each plot are very large.  I am able to assign variables to each plot and then use GraphicsGrid to view them all, but i have to copy and paste the input for each plot.  I am wondering if there is a way to create the plot, store it, then create the next plot and store  it along with the first, and so on.  This way when i am done creating all plots I can just view them all and compare them together in a grid.  I have attempted to use AppendTo, but i am unable to even store two plots, as the first plot is erased in some manner.  Here is an example of how I start:

```
        SetDirectory["Z:\\130709"];
        filename = "af.txt";
    datafile = Import[filename, "CSV"];
        plot = ListLinePlot[datafile]
filename2 ="ai.txt";
datafile2 = Import[filename2,"CSV"];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[datafile2]
AppendTo[plot,plot2]
```

So I am trying to store the plot, and then my hope is to just change the input filename and continue on to save space.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `AppendTo[{plot}, plot2]` work? If the plots are large, I think you can consider `Rasterize` them, which I think would be faster.

Answer (score 4):

I guess your data files are named well, I mean according to some pattern.

However here is a n example

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

(*creating data file with serial name*)
Table[Export[StringJoin[ToString[n], ".dat"],
Table[{x, Sin[n x]}, {x, 0., 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/10.}], "Table"], {n, 1, 3}]
```

This will create three data file `{"1.dat", "2.dat", "3.dat"}`.
Now you can `Import` data from files, one by one,  and put all the `Plot`s in a table.

```
graph = Table[data = Import[StringJoin[ToString[n], ".dat"]]; 
ListLinePlot[data], {n, 1, 3}];
graph // TableForm
```

`graph` has all your plots. You can put all of them in a table or can call the individually.

Comment: this helps, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `Grid` for your plot and then export the grid.

let us take an example:

```
Export["plot.jpg", 
 Grid[{ {ListPlot[RandomReal[1, 100]],Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]} }]
]
```

> [image]